# Creacion de un select en C#

Tags: c#, sql, base-de-datos

Buenos dias necesito ayuda con la creacion de un select en la base de datos y mostrar los resultados en un textbox Pero me dice que el nombre de la columnma es invalido el codigo es el siguiente:

```
        SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:XYZ.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Gestion;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=US3R1D;Password=P@$$W0RD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
        conexion.Open();
        string cod = TxtCodigo.Text;
        string cadena = "select Nombre,Transporte,Placa from CodigoBarra where Codigo=" + TxtCodigo.Text;
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
        SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
        if (registro.Read())
        {

            TxtNombre.Text = registro["Nombre"].ToString();
            ComboTipo.Text = registro["Transporte"].ToString();
            TxtPlaca.Text = registro["Placa"].ToString();
            //desactivar campos de texto 
            TxtNombre.Enabled = false;
            ComboTipo.Enabled = false;
            TxtPlaca.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("NO SE ENCONTRO la caja seleccionada");

        }
        conexion.Close();
```

y esta seria la tabla en sql server
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cada vez que uses el sitio para hacer preguntas, recuerda limpiar las credenciales, no se te vaya a pasar una que funcione y la que se arma, liada parda en todo el sentido de la palabra x.x

Comment: solo para probar quita el where, prueba y me dices

Comment: Funciona pero solo toma el ultimo registro guardado

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que el campo Codigo es varchar, entonces si quieres usar ese campo el contenido debe ir entre comilla simples.
Ejemplo: Where Codigo = '001'

Intenta de esta manera:

```
    SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection("Server=tcp:XYZ.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=Gestion;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=US3R1D;Password=P@$$W0RD;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;");
    conexion.Open();
    string cod = TxtCodigo.Text;
    string cadena = "select Nombre,Transporte,Placa from CodigoBarra where Codigo = 'cod' ";
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(cadena, conexion);
    SqlDataReader registro = comando.ExecuteReader();
    if (registro.Read())
    {

        TxtNombre.Text = registro["Nombre"].ToString();
        ComboTipo.Text = registro["Transporte"].ToString();
        TxtPlaca.Text = registro["Placa"].ToString();
        //desactivar campos de texto 
        TxtNombre.Enabled = false;
        ComboTipo.Enabled = false;
        TxtPlaca.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("NO SE ENCONTRO la caja seleccionada");

    }
    conexion.Close();
```